# How to adjust HTML table according to DIV width and height?

Tags: css, html

I have PSD formated file converted into HTML.This HTML table placed inside a DIV which width is fixed to 16%. Now the HTML table is not adjusting itself to the DIV width.How can I amend?

***The HTML table(left-menu.html)**

```
<!-- Save for Web Slices (left side panel only(with orange tabs).psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="1339" height="753" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>.............................</td>
            <td>.............................</td>
            <td>.............................</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
```

**The style for DIV**

```
.left 
{
 height: 100%;
// background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 width: 16%;
 }
```

**The main HTML Page**

```
    <aside id="left-menu">
      <?php
    include ('left-menu.html');
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set your table width to : width="1339" that is the problem.

You can't shrink the size of the table by wrapping it inside the div.

You can set div for example to fixed width of X and then set table width to 100%... you are just doing it backwards ..

You can also try the following in CSS, you can set the minimum width of your div with "min-width:" lets say 16% of a 1000px window so you set it to min-width: 160px; and add width: 100% this way it will initially use only 16% of the available but if re-sized it will expand.

Comment: Thanks @LJ-C, I tried the min-width and also by making table width 100% but doesn't work.Since the table derived by converting PSD file,changing the width and height of it doesn't make the table look as it is.

Comment: Can you show us image of the template I can't picture it in my head. Because of width="1339" height="753" you can't do anything to it by wrapping it in a div. If you put wrap of 500px it won't work because it wouldn't shrink and it would overflow the div container. But if you add overflow: hidden; it would hide the extra content that is outside the 500px; so if your table MUST be 1339px wide there is no way of shrinking it to 16% of the current div unless your main container is extremely massive like 10 x 1339 :) sorry

Comment: this is the link where u can view the page itself..the one on the left side is what I'm trying to work on ,so that it wont overlap with the middle div as it is now.http://183.81.165.27/~vani/project/superstar.php

Comment: If I am seeing and understanding your website correctly you may add to the ".left" property "overflow:hidden;" this will hide anything that overlaps

Comment: after adding overflow :hidden,it became like this;http://183.81.165.27/~vani/project/superstar.php

Comment: Hmm it looks the same on my end.. do you have a photo editor that you can maybe draw how you want ti to look compared to now.

Comment: Actually I want the missing part to be displayed as well inside the 16% div in full

Comment: Yeah in that case you will need to shrink your table :(, doing it blind I would say maybe instead of width="1339" try width="100%" but one thing is 100% sure is that you can't shrink fixed size table with div wrap :( sorry

Comment: yes I tried width=100% but doesn't work,so there's no other way at all?

Comment: Sorry not that I know :(

Comment: hmm it's okay ..Thank u for helping anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found that the fixed width definietly cannot fit inside DIV. so must set each and every
 `<td>` element inside the table in % instead of PX. It will take pretty long to get it done but it helps..